# Why distinct is not working With Laravel + Postgresql?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to count the number of rows having distinct values on **ONLY ONE COLUMN**. For example, If I have `activities` table in which there is `email` column, I want to count the number of columns having distinct value in `email` column.

I am using **Laravel** + **PostgreSQL**. I tried the following code but it's counting all the rows!

```
$emailsCount = DB::table('activities')
    ->where('user_id',$UserId)
    ->distinct('email')
    ->count();
```

Later, I came to know that `distinct()` will not take any arguments, I tried to find a solution to my problem and someone(Other Stackoverflow Questions) suggested me to use `groupBy` just like the following code.

```
$emailsCount = DB::table('activities')
    ->where('user_id',$UserId)
    ->groupBy('email')
    ->count();
```

But it's returning wrong information. For example, In my case, It's returning `1` but I can see lots and lots of different emails in `email` column. I don't know what's wrong. How can I do this in the right way?

Comment: it returns 1 because you are using `->where('id',$UserId)` and there is just one activity whit the `id` equals `$UserId` !!

Comment: No, Each user ID can have multiple email ID!

Comment: Can you show the `activities` structure ? and i did not understand what do you mean by Each user ID can have multiple email ID ?

Comment: Here we go! But Sorry, in question, I was supposed to write `user_id` not `id`. STRUCTURE -> id, user_id, email, content, created_at, updated_at

Comment: Ok, and you can have two records with the same userId and two different emails ??

Comment: Try this `$emailsCount = DB::table('activities')
    ->where('user_id',$UserId)
    ->distinct()
    ->count(["email"]);` !!

Comment: That works!!!! Seriously, I don't know why I didn't get this idea! Thanks a lot, man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `distinct()` don't take any arguments, instead you can passe that parameter to the `count`method like this :

```
$emailsCount = DB::table('activities') 
                   ->where('user_id',$UserId) 
                   ->distinct() 
                   ->count(["email"]);
```